# Generate all combinations of vector with consecutive occurrences is considered as single occurrence

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I want to generate vectors with all possible combinations of vector elements where a consecutive multiple occurrences of an element is considered as single occurrence of that element.

**Simple cases**

For n = 2,

```
original <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
      v1 <- c("b","b","b","a","a","a")
```

So all unique occurrences of a swap with b.

For n = 3, we get

```
original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
    ver1<-c("a","a","a","c","c","c","b","b","b")
    ver2<-c("b","b","b","a","a","a","c","c","c")
    ver3<-c("b","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","a")
    ver4<-c("c","c","c","b","b","b","a","a","a")
    ver5<-c("c","c","c","a","a","a","b","b","b")
```

So all unique occurrences of `a` swap with `b` and `c`, all unique occurrences of `b` swap with `a` and `c` AND all unique occurrences of `c` swap with `b` and `a`.

The cases go up to n = 10. (I believe the possible vectors with different combinations are 10!)

Also, there can be more than a single chunk of a, b, c...

**Complex case**

For n = 2;

```
original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b")
    ver1<-c("b","b","b","a","a","a","b","b","a","a")
```

But if we swap the elements correctly the complex case and simple case should not matter.

What I am trying: (for n=2)

```
original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b")
ver1<-replace(original,which(original=='a'),'b')
ver1<-replace(ver1,which(original=='b'),'a')
gives ver1<-c("b","b","b","a","a","a","b","b","a","a")
```

But not sure how to automate this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an approach using the very fast `arrangements` package for permutations. We calculate the permutations of integers corresponding to the unique elements of the input and then do some clever indexing to output the corresponding swaps. This is extremely fast on small examples and does pretty well on larger example - on my computer it took a little less than 7 seconds to generate the `10! = 3628800` swaps on input of size 30 with 10 unique elements. The results are conveniently returned in a `list`.

```
library(arrangements)

all_swaps = function(x) {
  ux = unique(x)
  xi = as.integer(factor(x))
  perm = permutations(seq_along(ux))
  apply(perm, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(p) ux[p][xi], simplify = FALSE)
}
```

Test cases from the question:

```
# n = 2
all_swaps(c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b"))
# [[1]]
#  [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b"
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a"

## n = 3
all_swaps(c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a"
```

A shorter demo with 3 unique elements in a "complex" case where the elements are not all consecutive:

```
all_swaps(c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "b"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "c" "c" "b" "c"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "b" "a" "a" "c" "a"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "c"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "c" "a" "a" "b" "a"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "c" "b" "b" "a" "b"
```

A larger case:

```
# n = 10
set.seed(47)
start_t = Sys.time()
n10 = all_swaps(sample(letters[1:10], size = 30, replace = TRUE))
end_t = Sys.time()
end_t - start_t
# Time difference of 6.711215 secs
length(n10)
# [1] 3628800
```

---

### Benchmarking

Benchmarking my answer with Maël's and ThomasIsCoding's, my method relying on the `arrangements` package is quick and memory efficient. ThomasIsCoding's answer can be improved by changing from `pracma::perms` to `arrangements::permutations`--the memory usage is especially improved--but my version still performs better. Maël's uses a lot of time and memory. I'll lead with results, code to reproduce is below.

```
## 5 Unique Elements
arrange(b5, desc(`itr/sec`))
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression                  min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr>             <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 GregorThomas             2.31ms   12.6ms     77.5     5.77KB        0    40     0      516ms
# 2 ThomasIsCodingArr(in5)    9.3ms   20.5ms     47.4    19.55KB        0    24     0      506ms
# 3 ThomasIsCoding(in5)     12.57ms   22.7ms     41.2    45.41KB        0    22     0      534ms
# 4 Mael                   963.64ms  963.6ms      1.04    1.24MB        0     1     0      964ms
# # … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>

## 9 Unique Elements - memory allocation is important
arrange(b9, desc(`itr/sec`))
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression               min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   <bch:expr>          <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# 1 GregorThomas            1.8s     1.8s     0.556    27.7MB    0         1     0       1.8s <NULL>
# 2 ThomasIsCoding(in9)     2.5s     2.5s     0.400   230.8MB    0.400     1     1       2.5s <NULL>
# # … with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Benchmarking code:

```
## Functions
library(arrangements)
library(pracma)
ThomasIsCoding <- function(x) {
  idx <- match(x, unique(x))
  m <- asplit(matrix(unique(x)[perms(1:max(idx))], ncol = max(idx)), 1)
  Map(`[`, m, list(idx))
}
ThomasIsCodingArr <- function(x) {
  idx <- match(x, unique(x))
  m <- asplit(matrix(unique(x)[permutations(1:max(idx))], ncol = max(idx)), 1)
  Map(`[`, m, list(idx))
}
Mael <- function(vec){
  uni <- unique(vec)
  size <- length(uni)
  pVec <- paste(uni, collapse = "")
  grid <- expand.grid(rep(list(uni), size))
  expanded <- grid[apply(grid, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == size,]
  p <- unname(apply(expanded, 1, paste0, collapse = ""))
  
  lapply(p, function(x) chartr(pVec, x, vec))
}
all_swaps = function(x) {
  ux = unique(x)
  xi = as.integer(factor(x))
  perm = permutations(seq_along(ux))
  apply(perm, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(p) ux[p][xi], simplify = FALSE)
}

set.seed(47)
in5 = c(sample(letters[1:5], 5), sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace = TRUE))

b5 = bench::mark(
  GregorThomas = all_swaps(in5),
  Mael = Mael(in5),
  ThomasIsCoding(in5),
  ThomasIsCodingArr(in5),
  check = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: Thanks! I thought something like this would work, I followed the thread through and it came together quite elegantly :)

Comment: Looks great! examples works great in my RStudio on mac, but I am having issue with the '\' character on my server where I use R in command line in ubuntu. I have all work related to that on the server. Any work around that symbol?

Comment: You need R version 4.1 or greater for that anonymous function syntax. You can replace `\(p)` with `function(p)` for the same meaning.

Comment: @GregorThomas Nice work!  My instinct too was to map each "clump" (or "streak") of values to a single `streak_id`; then find all permutations of those `streak_id`s, which are notably fewer than the original values; and finally map each `streak_id` to its set of values.  I really wish the **`runner`** package had a `streak_id()` function to complement its `streak_run()`, but alas, I've had to improvise my own: `streak_id <- function(x) {cumsum(c(TRUE, (x != dplyr::lag(x))[-1]))}`.

Comment: @Greg Yeah, I feel like the question is almost misleading with the first sentence mentioning *"consecutive multiple occurrences"*. In actuality, streaks don't matter at all for the problem at hand - it's just value swapping. That the values may or may not be in streaks is of no consequence. I do think your `streak_id` function is equivalent to `data.table::rleid` (but nice concise implementation!).

Comment: @GregorThomas  Thanks for the reply!  Am I misinterpreting the question, then?  My approach would treat `x <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a")` as having three "elements", where each element is a "contiguous region" of the same value.  Did OP mean to treat `x` as having only two "***non***contiguous regions": `c("a", "a", "a", NULL, NULL "a")` and `c(NULL, NULL, NULL, "b", "b", NULL)`?  And the distinct values from `x` would "take turns" at "filling up" each region?

Comment: (+1) Very nice! I completely agree that "consecutive occurrences" felt like a red herring. You could simplify a bit further by not converting the factor to integers (`fx <- factor(x)`), taking `permutations(levels(fx))`, and then just indexing with the factor (`\(p) p[fx]`).

Comment: (Stritcly into code golf territory here, but the function body could come down to `f <- factor(x); l <- levels(f); p <- permutations(l); apply(p, 1L, "[", f)` -- I'm mostly sharing this because I think that form has some nice symmetries, if you happen to care about aesthetics in code :D)

Comment: Thanks Mikko! That is a nice simplification, and very aesthetically pleasant.

Comment: @Greg Yes, if you ignore the text of the question and focus on the examples, you'll see that in OP's "complex" case with multiple runs of "a" and "b" the desired output is (1) the original vector and (2) the vector with all "a"s and "b"s swapped, with no other variations. The contiguous regions don't matter at all, they can be ignored completely.

Comment: @Greg OP is somewhat aware of this - they say *"The cases go up to `n = 10`. (I believe the possible vectors with different combinations are `10!`)"* where `n` is the number of unique elements---`n` doesn't care about contiguous regions (inferred from OP's last "complex n = 2" example where there are 4 contiguous regions and 2 unique elements).

Comment: @Maël Benchmarks added.

Comment: Very nice benchmarking and also the use of `permuations`, upvoted! I also following your suggestion and made some improvement on my answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Update

Here we made some improvement on the previous answer, where the result is stored in `matrix` (instead of `list`), and `arrangement::permuations` is applied (instead of `pracma::perms` (thank recommendation from [@Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71162698/12158757))

```
f_TIC2 <- function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  idx <- match(x, u)
  n <- max(idx)
  m <- matrix(u[perms(1:n)], ncol = n)
  matrix(t(m)[c(outer(idx, (0:(nrow(m) - 1)) * ncol(m), `+`))], nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
}

f_TIC2Arr <- function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  idx <- match(x, u)
  n <- max(idx)
  m <- matrix(u[permutations(1:n)], ncol = n)
  matrix(t(m)[c(outer(idx, (0:(nrow(m) - 1)) * ncol(m), `+`))], nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
}
```

and the output looks like

```
> f_TIC2(c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b"))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "c"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "b"
[2,] "c"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "a"
[3,] "b"  "c"  "c"  "a"  "c"
[4,] "b"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "a"
[5,] "a"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "b"
[6,] "a"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "c"

> f_TIC2Arr(c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b"))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "b"
[2,] "a"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "c"
[3,] "b"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "a"
[4,] "b"  "c"  "c"  "a"  "c"
[5,] "c"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "a"
[6,] "c"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "b"
```

## Benchmarking

Here is a benchmark among some of the existing answers (Maël's solution is computational heavy, thus being skipped.)

**NB**: This benchmark is **NOT** 100% fair since my improved solutions yield matrices rather than lists, which save a lot of time. Thus, the comparsion is ***not saying mine is the fastest but indicating the possible approaches to improve the performance***.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(arrangements)
library(pracma)
f_TIC1 <- function(x) {
  idx <- match(x, unique(x))
  m <- asplit(matrix(unique(x)[perms(1:max(idx))], ncol = max(idx)), 1)
  Map(`[`, m, list(idx))
}
f_TIC1Arr <- function(x) {
  idx <- match(x, unique(x))
  m <- asplit(matrix(unique(x)[permutations(1:max(idx))], ncol = max(idx)), 1)
  Map(`[`, m, list(idx))
}
f_TIC2 <- function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  idx <- match(x, u)
  n <- max(idx)
  m <- matrix(u[perms(1:n)], ncol = n)
  matrix(t(m)[outer(idx, (0:(nrow(m) - 1)) * ncol(m), `+`)], nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
}

f_TIC2Arr <- function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  idx <- match(x, u)
  n <- max(idx)
  m <- matrix(u[permutations(1:n)], ncol = n)
  matrix(t(m)[outer(idx, (0:(nrow(m) - 1)) * ncol(m), `+`)], nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
}

f_GT <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  xi <- as.integer(factor(x))
  perm <- permutations(seq_along(ux))
  apply(perm, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(p) ux[p][xi], simplify = FALSE)
}

f_RS <- function(x) {
  permuteGeneral(uv <- unique(x), length(uv), FUN = \(m) uv[match(x, m)])
}

set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters[1:10], 10, replace = TRUE)

bm <- bench::mark(
  f_GT = f_GT(x),
  f_TIC1 = f_TIC1(x),
  f_TIC1Arr = f_TIC1Arr(x),
  f_TIC2 = f_TIC2(x),
  f_TIC2Arr = f_TIC2Arr(x),
  f_RS = f_RS(x),
  check = FALSE
)
autoplot(bm)
```

and you will see

```
> bm
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 f_GT       11.55ms 15.57ms      58.9  315.14KB     7.06    25     3      425ms
2 f_TIC1     17.05ms  20.8ms      45.5    2.58MB    10.1     18     4      396ms
3 f_TIC1Arr  16.45ms 19.62ms      48.9    1.06MB    13.6     18     5      368ms
4 f_TIC2      2.47ms  3.31ms     259.     3.84MB    28.5     91    10      351ms
5 f_TIC2Arr   1.54ms   1.7ms     469.     2.35MB    26.2    197    11      420ms
6 f_RS        5.66ms  7.46ms      93.9   72.75KB     9.63    39     4      415ms
# ... with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>,
#   gc <list>
```

and

[image]

---

## Previous Answer

You can try `pracma::perms` like below

```
library(pracma)
f <- function(x) {
  idx <- match(x, unique(x))
  m <- asplit(matrix(unique(x)[perms(1:max(idx))], ncol = max(idx)), 1)
  Map(`[`, m, list(idx))
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"))
[[1]]
 [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a"

[[2]]
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b"


> f(c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b"))
[[1]]
[1] "c" "b" "b" "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "a" "a" "b" "a"

[[3]]
[1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "c"

[[4]]
[1] "b" "a" "a" "c" "a"

[[5]]
[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "b"

[[6]]
[1] "a" "c" "c" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Would you post benchmark stats like 'mem_alloc' as if i go to n=10 which method is best for time and memory. Can you check if f_TIC2Arr() works for n=2? as it seems to give an error for original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b"

Comment: @RahilVora Sorry that I forgot to add `c()` outside `outer`. Please see my update and I guess now the issue is resolved.

Comment: @RahilVora I added `mem_alloc` for benchmarking. Please check it out.

Comment: This is really nice

Answer (score 5):

Using `chartr`, you can do (although this might crash for larger vectors):

```r
f <- function(vec){
  uni <- unique(vec)
  size <- length(uni)
  pVec <- paste(uni, collapse = "")
  grid <- expand.grid(rep(list(uni), size))
  expanded <- grid[apply(grid, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == size,]
  p <- unname(apply(ex, 1, paste0, collapse = ""))
  
  lapply(p, function(x) chartr(pVec, x, vec))
}
```

output:

```r
original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
f(original)

# [[1]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

---

**Previous answer** (do not work for n > 2).

Using `gtools::permutations`. Results are each columns of the matrix. The idea is to get the permutations from unique values, and the repeat the values to match the desired group length.

```r
f <- function(x){
  r <- rle(x)
  l <- length(r$values)
  apply(gtools::permutations(n=l, r=l, v=r$values), 1, function(x) rep(x, each = unique(r$l)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, how to convert all columns to individual vectors at once as at the end I want to compare my_vector(different) to all new vectors along with original to see how many elements match

Comment: You can convert to data.frame then to list `as.list(as.data.frame(f(original)))`. Depends on what you need.

Comment: This does not work for the complex cases such as mention above for n=2 original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b"), or unequal length original<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c")

Answer (score 5):

This answer takes the same general approach to those already posted but uses `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral()` which is not only very fast but also allows functions to be applied to the permutations.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

f <- function(x) permuteGeneral(uv <- unique(x), length(uv), FUN = \(m) uv[match(x, m)])

f(original)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c"

[[4]]
[1] "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"

[[5]]
[1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a"

[[6]]
[1] "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a"
```

Comment: Impressive! What a powerful `permuteGeneral`! Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Here is base R solution:

```
vec <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")  # original vector
els <- unique(vec)                             # unique elements

pers <- do.call(expand.grid, args=rep(list(els), length(els)))  # all permutations
pers <- as.matrix(pers[apply(pers, 1, anyDuplicated) == 0,])    # no repeated cases
colnames(pers) <- els

unname(pers[,vec])

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "c"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "a"  "a"
[2,] "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "c"  "a"  "a"  "a"
[3,] "c"  "c"  "c"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"
[4,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "b"  "b"
[5,] "b"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "c"  "c"
[6,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "c"
```